# How to add Header to List View In Android

Tags: android, header, view

Just as title...
 I am new.
 Could someone give me some easy examples, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the examples are:

1. [Android ListView Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)
2. [ListView with headers above sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394514/how-to-generate-a-listview-with-headers-above-some-sections)

AND it's important to read the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) first.

if you like to have another example, a simple google search would do. :)

Answer (score 9):

There are so many ways of adding **Headers** to list view

1. For Sticky Header, check [this](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/).
2. For Android Categorized listview with heading, check this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539480/android-categorized-listview-with-heading).
3. You can find source code at [this](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b3g5g1b/n/TestSectionedHeaderList.zip)
4. For android-amazing-listview, check [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

These are the examples of Different types of list view.