# how to settittle to listview in infater layout?

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I'm new to android..

I'm facing problem with tittle for listview..

How to implement tittle for list view? help me..

I try like this..

> ```
>       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>       viewList = Nexttopic.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_nexttopic, null);
>       dialogMarketList = new Dialog(Nexttopic.this);
>       dialogMarketList.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>       dialogMarketList.setTitle("TOPICS");
>       dialogMarketList.setContentView(viewList);
>       dialogMarketList.show();     
>       lvForDialog = (ListView) viewList.findViewById(R.id.List_view);
>       lvForDialog.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
>       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(Nexttopic.this, R.layout.row_topic, R.id.child_row,tnamelist));
>       lvForDialog.setAdapter(adapter);
> ```

Its not working..

Comment: ues this link https://www.google.co.in/search?sclient=psy-ab&q=How+to+set+the+title+of+listview+in+android&btnG=

Comment: check my edited ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16076659/1168654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove this:

```
dialogMarketList.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

---

### Edited answer:

[image]

use this way:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewList = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main_, null);
        dialogMarketList = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogMarketList.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogMarketList.setTitle("TOPICS");
        dialogMarketList.setContentView(viewList);
        dialogMarketList.show();
        ListView lvForDialog = (ListView) viewList.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);

        lvForDialog.addHeaderView(header);
        lvForDialog.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, a));
        lvForDialog.setAdapter(adapter);
```

header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="my title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

---

**Edited 2nd time:**

### avoid title go up when scrolling use below code insted of above.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("my Title");
        builder.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        builder.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.row, R.id.child_row, items),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    }
                });

        builder.show();
```

Comment: its came but i need that in centre and i want to add backgroung image to tittle. how to implement this...

Comment: @OneManArmy: check my edited 2nd time ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16076659/1168654

Comment: for AlertDialog.Builder you can't add close mark on top but you can add cancle or ok button at bottom like --> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

The following command in your code disables the title in the dialog:

```
dialogMarketList.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

If you remove it you should see the dialog with the title.

Answer (score 0):

You are possible want to add a header to listview?

Look add this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10730786/1293704

Many tutorials can be found how to add a header.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `headerView` in your `listView`, you need to do it before you call `setAdapter()`

What [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) says /

```
public void addHeaderView (View v)
```

*Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the list. If addHeaderView is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.
 NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header and footer views.