# Why app crashing? ListView with different views

Tags: android, android-listview

I try to create ListView as settings page.
First line is EditText;
2-5 lines are two texts.

So my Adapter class :

```
public class SettingsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final int TYPE_NAME = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SETTING = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = 2;

    SPMEditActionActivity   context;
    LayoutInflater          inflater;
    ArrayList               data;


    SettingsAdapter(SPMEditActionActivity _context) {

        context = _context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        data = new ArrayList();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            data.add("Hello");
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position==0 ? TYPE_NAME : TYPE_SETTING;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    // пункт списка
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);


        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            if(type == TYPE_NAME)
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editactionactivity_settings_name, parent, false);
            else
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editactionactivity_setting, parent, false);

        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
public class SPMEditActionActivity extends Activity {


    final int START_TIME_DIALOG = 1;
    final int END_TIME_DIALOG = 2;

//==============UI===============================================
    private ListView        settings_listview ; 
    private SettingsAdapter settings_adapter;

    private Button save_button;
    private Button cancel_button;
//==============================================================

//========UI LISTENERS==========================================


        private OnClickListener save_button_listener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 save();
            }
        };      
        private OnClickListener cancel_button_listener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 cancel();
            }
        };

//==============================================================

//==============================================================

//=================LIFECYCLE METHODS============================
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spmeditaction);



        save_button  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.EditActionActivity_save_button);
        cancel_button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.EditActionActivity_cancel_button);

        settings_adapter = new SettingsAdapter(SPMEditActionActivity.this);
        settings_listview.setAdapter(  settings_adapter    );


        save_button.setOnClickListener(save_button_listener);
        cancel_button.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_listener);


    }

//==============================================================
    private void save(){
        finish();

    }

    private void cancel(){
        finish();
    }

}
```

And in activity, when I set adapter

```
settings_adapter = new SettingsAdapter(this);
settings_listview.setAdapter(  settings_adapter    );
```

my app crashing with NullPointerException .

Can anyone explain to me, what I doing wrong?

PS. I use this [tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

LogCat output :

```
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hemul.soundprofilemanager/com.hemul.soundprofilemanager.SPMEditActionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 15:59:19.982:E/AndroidRuntime(24150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at com.hemul.soundprofilemanager.SPMEditActionActivity.onCreate(SPMEditActionActivity.java:111)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-18 15:59:19.982: E/AndroidRuntime(24150):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full stack trace?

Comment: insted of this use listvie.setheader(view); for you TYPE_NAME check this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16076659/1168654

Comment: I see this request of posting the LogCat on almost every other question. Is their a way to educate the new users(in android community atleast) about the importance of posting LogCat? If this is done as soon as they are about to post their first question with tag of android, it would really help.

Comment: Post your SPMEditActionActivity, there is an exception in ilne no 111

Comment: 111 line is settings_listview.setAdapter(  settings_adapter    );

Comment: @Hemul Post your SPMEditActionActivity completele

Comment: @Hemul I have posted answer...Check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your  `settings_listview` is null, because you haven't assigned a reference to this in onCreate

get your listview reference from xml like this

```
settings_listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourlistview);  <-- your listview id in xml
```

after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_spmeditaction);`