# how to disable an item in my ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` set in my `AlertDialog` in Android and i'm trying to add separators as heading titles to help organize the information. I figured out how to display them... but they are still selectable by the user which isn't good.

Is there a way to disable an item to be selectable in an Android `ListView`? I found an method `isEnabled(int position)` to see if an item is enabled or not but none to see if its disabled.

Comment: if you can post your code.. it will help us answering your questions..

Comment: @jfisk: See this post, may be it is of any help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966802/android-listview-headers

Answer (score 9):

**Just Now i have implemented it**

```
ListView list=new ListView(this);
list.getChildAt(0).setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: sorry, i try this, but error 08-06 20:36:29.045: E/AndroidRuntime(31116): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.imotax/com.imotax.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 4):

override this in ur code to disable the focus.

```
         @Override
         public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return false;
           }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found a lot of comments saying that

```
setEnabled(false)
setClickable(false)
setFocusable(false)
```

would work, but the answer is **NO**

The only workaround for this approach is doing:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_storage_divider, parent, false);
view.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Comment: Answer by Randroid works for me. setOnClickListener(null) works but means you cannot get back to having a listener again. Extending ArrayAdapter is the correct answer i believe.

Answer (score 0):

setClickable(False) works fine for me . try it once . in case problem will be persist i will share my custom adapter with you.