# How to add a textview between listitems of listview?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I need to add a textview in a listview in between listitems. 
How can i make it possible.

I have a listview with listitems and i would like to add a textview as a separator between a group of listitems list like a group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean that you want to add textview to each list item?

Comment: I need text view in between the listitems. Not in regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 types of xml files for list items - first for "usual" list item ant second for item with textview. And set them in adapter appropriately.

Comment: Setting them in the adapter is the harder part that I'm struggling at. What layout should I pass to the super function in my list view inflater? The one with text view or the one without it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966802/android-listview-headers) post. It is basically the same as grouping items with headers except you will have each item with its "header".