# Android multiple list views that don't scroll independently

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to create a page that has 3 lists and 3 headers but I don't want to scroll them independently, I want the whole page to scroll. Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Essentially I want it to look like this:

```
header
smlheader
list
smlheader
list
smlheader
list
```

With this code I've tried to achieve it but it's not that good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

   <include layout="@layout/header" />
   <include layout="@layout/redcell" />

   <TableRow

       android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="60dp" >


      <TextView

        android:id="@+id/fixtures_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/leagues"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>




   </TableRow>

   <include layout="@layout/redcell" />

   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="60dp" >


      <TextView

        android:id="@+id/results_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/leagues"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

   </TableRow>

    <include layout="@layout/redcell" />


    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   />

</TableLayout>
<ScrollView/>
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1967010/1321873

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you want... do you want three lists side-by-side that scroll together, or three lists that are arranged vertically but scroll as one list?

Comment: What have you tried? Without seeing the code you've used we can't help you.

Comment: three lists that are arranged vertically that scroll as one list

Comment: also i have edited my question to show what i have tried so far i tried to achieve it with table rows

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would try CommonsWare [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) as pointed to by Rajesh.  It sounds like exactly what you need.

It will take multiple views (including listviews) and put them together, then you set the merge adapter to a listview and presto, you have several listviews in one.

Quoting from the docs for it:

MergeAdapter accepts a mix of Adapters and Views and presents them as one contiguous whole to whatever ListView it is poured into. This is good for cases where you have multiple data sources, or if you have a handful of ordinary Views to mix in with lists of data, or the like.

Simply create a MergeAdapter and call addAdapter(), addView(), or addViews() (latter accepting a List), then attach your adapter to the ListView.

**EDIT**

1) Download the .jar from [here](https://github.com/downloads/commonsguy/cwac-merge/CWAC-MergeAdapter.jar)
2) Download the .jar for [CWAC SackOfViewsAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/blob/master/libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar) as the MergeAdapter requires it.
2) Create a directory in your project called "libs" (on the same level as src & res)
3) place both of the .jar files in that folder  (Eclipse should automatically take things from there as far as setting it up to be included in the build)
4) Use the MergeAdapter per the instructions from the first link in my original response.

Pseudo-code example:

```
myMergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();
myMergeAdapter.addView(HeaderView);
myMergeAdapter.addView(SmallHeaderView1);
myMergeAdapter.addAdapter(listAdapter1);
myMergeAdapter.addView(SmallHeaderView2);
myMergeAdapter.addAdapter(listAdapter2);
myMergeAdapter.addView(SmallHeaderView3);
myMergeAdapter.addAdapter(listAdapter3);

setListAdapter(myMergeAdapter);
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding your header which is a complete layout:

```
View Header = getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.red_cell);
myMergeAdapter.addView(Header);
```

Comment: yeah this sound s about right but how do i implement this into my code?

Comment: also do i need to change the layout file. i have a layout out file called red cell which is just a red bar with a text view thats what i want to use as xml header how do i call that from my layout folder to fit in with a mergeAdapter

Comment: its asking me to create a local variable container is this right. ps thank you again you are the most helpful person I've spoken to

Comment: @iamlukeyb, Nope.  My bad, I grabbed that from one of my projects where that variable is supplied.  I've modified my answer so it should work for you now.  Check it out.