# Android list sections

Tags: android, listview, onclick, categories

I need a simple way without any Custom listAdapters to create a ListView with sections, or Categories.

Its important the the Categorie separator doesn't count as a listItem, because i am using the my list items position in the onClick() so every item counts.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want section headers in a standard ListView, you're going to have to make your own adapter.

You could use an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), it sounds like exactly what you need.

**EDIT**

Ok, then you want to use MergeAdapter by CommonsWare.  I *just* posted about it for someone else, it'll work for you too.  I even included instructions.  :)

[MergeAdapter Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10535980/1105376)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I dont need an expandable. here is my situation: I am using a simpleAdapter for my listView, and using my own list row design from an XML file. I am afraid that since i dont know to use adapters ill mess it up, because i need everything the way it is right now. the onclick function has to be the same, and everything else. i have 2 lines of text and no idea how to do that or change them dynamically from a ListAdapter. So i must find a way to do it without, and i can't use an Expandable ListView.

Comment: @arielschon12, I've got just the thing for you then.  I've updated my answer, check it out.