# Categorized ListView like pure android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make a listView ... just like this .. any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: duplicate of [Android ListView Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966802/android-listview-headers) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers and many other SO questions. A trivial search for `android listview headers` also turns up open source components like http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/, blog posts like http://kmansoft.com/2010/11/16/adding-group-headers-to-listview/, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to use a `ListView` ..?

In case the elements are totally different, you **cannot** have a common layout for each row, i.e. the child elements. You can obviously use `ListView Headers` to achieve this and use `getView()` to determine whether to show the checkbox or not..

However, the easy (and probably unethical way) would be to simply use a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` , if you have too many elements to be displayed, assuming you have a fixed number of elements to be displayed which is known beforehand.

But, the best thing to do in your case would be to use a `PreferenceActivity`. It is the commonly used Activity for the Settings screen and is optimised for that purpose only, like user preferences in the settings screen of any application.

**EDIT** : As you mentioned in the comments that you only wish to display list of items in categories and not the checkboxes, I am assuming that you are not designing a Settings screen. In that matter, it would be relevant for you to use an `ExpandableListView`, where you can display the list of categories as parents and the items under each category as the children.

Or, as *@CommonsWare* sir already suggested in the comments to your question, use **headers for ListView** to display the categories.

Comment: I just one to make similar one .. with all rows are the same .. containing images and at text .. but with categories .. not checkboxes or other things

Comment: Why not go for `ExpandableListView` in that case..?

Comment: Or use `Group headers for ListView`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get something just like the picture you posted you could try a preference activity:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html