# Listview not filling its parent

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I have faced following problem:

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer with subheadings like the one in gmail app and one another app:

[image: VK]

[image: Gmail]

As you can see, I have higlighted that there are no dividers at the end of each list

SO I have taken an implementation with subheadings from stack overlfow and I have ended up with something like this:

[image: MyApp]
As you know, navigation drawer uses listview and the reason why divider is there is because subheading is also a list item so setting option footerDividerEnabled to false doesn't solve the problem.

So my next implementaiton was to put View which will contatin subheading and listview and then added to navigation-drawer's listview.

Here is my source code of MainActivity:

```
package com.myphun.radio;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.androidradio.R;
import com.myphun.ui.adapters.ListViewAdapter;
import com.myphun.ui.components.SlidingMenuLayout;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private SlidingMenuLayout mSlidingMenuLayout;
    private ListView leftDrawerList;
    private ListViewAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSlidingMenuLayout = (SlidingMenuLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_sliding_menu);
        leftDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_list);

        ViewArrayAdapter viewArrayAdapter = new ViewArrayAdapter(this);
        View generic_drawer_view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.sliding_menu_general_section_layout, null);
        viewArrayAdapter.add(generic_drawer_view);

        ListView genericCategoriesListView = (ListView) generic_drawer_view.findViewById(R.id.general_drawer_list);

        mAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this);

        mAdapter.addItem("Mercury", R.drawable.mercury);
        mAdapter.addItem("Venus", R.drawable.venus);
        mAdapter.addItem("Earth", R.drawable.earth);
        mAdapter.addItem("Mars", R.drawable.mars);

        mAdapter.addItem("Neptune", R.drawable.neptune);
        mAdapter.addItem("Saturn", R.drawable.saturn);
        mAdapter.addItem("Uranus", R.drawable.uranus);
        mAdapter.addItem("Jupiter", R.drawable.jupiter);

        genericCategoriesListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        leftDrawerList.setAdapter(viewArrayAdapter);
    }

}

class ViewArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<View>
{

    public ViewArrayAdapter(Context context)
    {
        super(context, 0, new ArrayList<View>());
    }

    public ViewArrayAdapter(Context context, List<View> viewsList)
    {
        super(context, 0, viewsList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return getItem(position);
    }
}
```

Main Activity XML:

```
 <com.myphun.ui.components.SlidingMenuLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_sliding_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView122"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#444444"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#555555"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

</com.myphun.ui.components.SlidingMenuLayout>
```

Custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/general_drawer_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/general_drawer_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="Planets"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/general_drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EE444444"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#555555"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But for some reason, listview doesn't fill entire screen:
[image: bad result]

I've tried many combination of xml_atributes (i.e. match_parent, wrap_content, fill_parent) and the only one which works is when you set ListView layout_height manually (i.e. layout_height ="625dp").

SO the question is:
What I'am doing wrong ? How can I achieve desire result ? Why is listview not expanding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I think you are committing an overkill adding `ListView` to a `ListView`.
It pretty much defats the purpose of using `ListView` with reusable views in the first place and makes your layout pretty complexed as you have to provide many adapters and many xml-layout files.

Let's get one thing straight - `NavigationDrawer` can contain any view you like not only `ListView`.

If your data does not fit in one-ListView concept maybe you should not use it at all ? Stick to the `LinearLayouts`. If you have some dynamic data then add it by `addView` method to your sub-LinearLayout (sections). If you have static navigation then declare directly in the layout xml file - you gain an opportunity to preview the layout without compiling the whole project.

If you want to put a lot of items to the NavigationDrawer maybe you should rethink the whole concept of the app? The navigation will basically become the content hence it should not be in the `NavigationDrawer`.

Hope it helps, regs.

Comment: It has helped a lot ! :) I have redesigned my app, so there is no more listview within listview ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already accepted an answer but it does not cover the first part of your question. Namely, how to get rid of the divider before a heading.

Firstly, not sure how you've implemented your `ListView` so that it handles different types of items (i.e. headings and regular rows) so a few references for the ones who are struggling with that. The [ListView Headers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13634801/392781) was most helpful for me but I also had a look at two other questions: [Navigation Drawer With Headers Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170396/navigation-drawer-with-headers-sections) and [Section Headers In Navigation Drawer Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040975/section-headers-in-navigation-drawer-listview).

Secondly, it is important to use the `ListView` divider correctly, i.e. do not use a background element on your row items in order to have a border at the bottom but use the `android:divider` and `android:dividerHeight` attributes. If you want to customise its appearance [read the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:divider).

Next, I have noticed that the divider is not displayed between a regular item and a heading **by default** (exactly what you have observed and pointed to in your pictures). I haven't found this feature documented anywhere, though.

Lastly, there's a tricky bit at the end. When a regular item is not followed by a heading, it will be followed by a divider. You need to add `android:footerDividersEnabled="false"` to your `ListView`.

PS. Your problem is more related to a `ListView` than to a Navigation Drawer - if you search for the former one you will definitely get more results.